# how to drag and drop from another widget on to a QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.6

I need to drag from a `QListWidget` or something similar and drop on a `QGraphicsScene`, and create a subclass of `QGraphicsItem` at the drop location.  Anyone have any ideas?  I'm using Qt 4.6.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drag and Drop Puzzle example seems to do what you are looking for: https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/draganddrop-puzzle.html